# How to get access to XHR in $http with Angular?

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest, progress-bar

Currently I am try to implement the upload function with Angular. At first I used XmlHttpRequest but later I changed it to $http. So I found that I could't get access to
XmlHttpRequest to create a progress bar with $http. Below is my code. Any suggestions about create a progress bar when uploading images? Thanks.

```
    $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: upload_url,
          data: fd, 
          headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}, 
          transformRequest: angular.identity
          })
```

Comment: Pls Refer :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033195/showing-spinner-gif-during-http-request-in-angular

Comment: That really helps in a different way, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here the way of getting xhr object:

http://boylesoftware.com/blog/angular-tip-using-the-xmlhttprequest-object/

## Copy/Paste:

> Normally, an AngularJS application uses the $http service to make
>   calls to back-end services. Sometimes, however, we would like to have
>   access to the underlying XMLHttpRequest object. I can come up with a
>   few use-cases, but the most prominent one is probably being able to
>   track progress of a long request, such as a file upload. To do that,
>   we need to register an event listener on the XMLHttpRequest object for
>   the event that is “in progress.” Surprisingly enough, Angular’s $http
>   service does not in any way expose the underlying XMLHttpRequest
>   object. So, we have to get creative. Here is one way to do it…
>
> The $http service’s config object allows us to add headers to the HTTP
>   request via its “headers” property. That means that at some point
>   $http has to set those headers on the XMLHttpRequest object it uses.
>   The way to do that is to use XMLHttpRequest’s setRequestHeader method.
>   So the idea is to override the setRequestHeader method on the
>   XMLHttpRequest’s prototype and use a special header name to introduce
>   a hook. Let’s begin with that and create a simple Angular module that
>   performs the method substitution in its configuration phase:

```
angular.module("bsworksXHR", []).config([
    function() {
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.setRequestHeader = (function(sup) {
            return function(header, value) {
                if ((header === "__XHR__") && angular.isFunction(value))
                    value(this);
                else
                    sup.apply(this, arguments);
            };
        })(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.setRequestHeader);
    }
]);
```

> Now, when we make an $http service call, we can add a header called
>   “**XHR**” with a function value that will receive the XMLHttpRequest
>   object as its only argument. For example, somewhere else in the
>   application:

```
$http({
    …
    headers: {
        …
        __XHR__: function() {
            return function(xhr) {
                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(event) {
                    console.log("uploaded " + ((event.loaded/event.total) * 100) + "%");
                });
            };
        },
        …
    },
    …
}).success(…);
```

> Hopefully, future versions of AngularJS will include some official way
>   to access the low-level XMLHttpRequest object, even if limited, such
>   as being able to register event listeners or translating the
>   XMLHttpRequest events into Angular events. Until then, I am using the
>   approach above in my apps.

Answer (score 0):

This can serve you:

```
            $http.post('http://url.com', {parameter1:'parameter', parameter2: 'secondparameter'}).success(function (result) {
                console.log(result.data);
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(status);
            }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $http config's eventHandlers property to register an XMLHttpRequest listener, which will give you the progress:

```
var onProgress = function(event) {
    if (event.total) {
        var progress = event.loaded * 100 / event.total;
        // do stuff
    }
};

$http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: upload_url,
      data: fd, 
      headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}, 
      transformRequest: angular.identity,
      uploadEventHandlers: { progress: onProgress }
      });
```

I think that should cover your use case.  I think you can also use `this` inside of an event listener to get the XmlHttpRequest instance.