# Angularjs loading screen on ajax request

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Using Angularjs , I need to show a loading screen (a simple spinner) until ajax request is complete. Please suggest any idea with a code snippet.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033195/showing-spinner-gif-during-http-request-in-angular

Comment: Best practice is using `$httpProvider.interceptors` since it can handle when ajax request start and when it end . That is why `$watch` is no longer needed to to detect when ajax call start and end.

Comment: how about you checkout my factory [angular-httpshooter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-httpshooter), it gives you better control for loaders and freezing UI

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Instead of setting up a scope variable to indicate data loading status, it is better to have a directive does everything for you:

```
angular.module('directive.loading', [])

    .directive('loading',   ['$http' ,function ($http)
    {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs)
            {
                scope.isLoading = function () {
                    return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
                };

                scope.$watch(scope.isLoading, function (v)
                {
                    if(v){
                        elm.show();
                    }else{
                        elm.hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        };

    }]);
```

With this directive, all you need to do is to give any loading animation element an 'loading' attribute:

```
<div class="loading-spiner-holder" data-loading ><div class="loading-spiner"><img src="..." /></div></div>
```

You can have multiple loading spinners on the page. where and how to layout those spinners is up to you and directive will simply turn it on/off for you automatically.

Comment: here "loading" directive is being called twice, with $location.path(). First with current page and next with the destination page. What should be the reason?

Comment: Excellent. And also, you can use jquery toggle on watch: elm.toggle(v). I have a $timeout session monitor, and for me, I need to show the spinner only after a half second. I will implements a css with transition to show more slowly the spinner.

Comment: If you get the "elm.show() is not a function" error, you must add jquery before loading angular.

Comment: The way you do scope.watch doesn't work for me. I had to do it the way that jzm does it (by using '' around the name and omitting the scope prefix). Any ideas why?

Comment: What if I need to async. load multiple different areas?

Comment: @DavidLin great. works good. but the thing is, if i have requests different areas in same page, it will show all the loaders for all the areas instead of particular area. how to do for particular area of request

Comment: how to turn off for a specific request

Answer (score 57):

Here's an example. It uses the simple ng-show method with a bool.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-show="loading" class="loading"><img src="...">LOADING...</div>
<div ng-repeat="car in cars">
  <li>{{car.name}}</li>
</div>
<button ng-click="clickMe()" class="btn btn-primary">CLICK ME</button>
```

**ANGULARJS**

```
  $scope.clickMe = function() {
    $scope.loading = true;
    $http.get('test.json')
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.cars = data[0].cars;
        $scope.loading = false;
    });
  }
```

Of course you can move the loading box html code into a directive, then use $watch on $scope.loading. In which case:

**HTML**:

```
<loading></loading>
```

**ANGULARJS DIRECTIVE**:

```
  .directive('loading', function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:true,
        template: '<div class="loading"><img src="..."/>LOADING...</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
              scope.$watch('loading', function (val) {
                  if (val)
                      $(element).show();
                  else
                      $(element).hide();
              });
        }
      }
  })
```

**PLUNK**: http://plnkr.co/edit/AI1z21?p=preview

Comment: The way you do scope.watch works for me wheras the accepted answer approach doesn't.

Comment: @jzm Such a great solution , unfortunately this solution not working with `ui-router`, don't know why

Comment: I did this in one of my project worked fine, in another project i think due to heavy ajax request `loading=true` do not get set

Answer (score 21):

I use [ngProgress](http://victorbjelkholm.github.io/ngProgress/) for this.

Add 'ngProgress' to your dependencies once you've included the script/css files in your HTML. Once you do that you can set up something like this, which will trigger when a route change was detected.

```
angular.module('app').run(function($rootScope, ngProgress) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(ev,data) {
    ngProgress.start();
  });
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(ev,data) {
    ngProgress.complete();
  });
});
```

For AJAX requests you can do something like this:

```
$scope.getLatest = function () {
    ngProgress.start();

    $http.get('/latest-goodies')
         .success(function(data,status) {
             $scope.latest = data;
             ngProgress.complete();
         })
         .error(function(data,status) {
             ngProgress.complete();
         });
};
```

Just remember to add 'ngProgress' to the controllers dependencies before doing so. And if you are doing multiple AJAX requests use an incremental variable in the main app scope to keep track when your AJAX requests have finished before calling 'ngProgress.complete();'.

Answer (score 15):

using pendingRequests is not correct because as mentioned in Angular documentation, this property is primarily meant to be used for debugging purposes.

What I recommend is to use an interceptor to know if there is any active Async call.

```
module.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, $rootScope) {
        if ($rootScope.activeCalls == undefined) {
            $rootScope.activeCalls = 0;
        }

        return {
            request: function (config) {
                $rootScope.activeCalls += 1;
                return config;
            },
            requestError: function (rejection) {
                $rootScope.activeCalls -= 1;
                return rejection;
            },
            response: function (response) {
                $rootScope.activeCalls -= 1;
                return response;
            },
            responseError: function (rejection) {
                $rootScope.activeCalls -= 1;
                return rejection;
            }
        };
    });
}]);
```

and then check whether activeCalls is zero or not in the directive through a $watch.

```
module.directive('loadingSpinner', function ($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div class="loader unixloader" data-initialize="loader" data-delay="500"></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$watch('activeCalls', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal == 0) {
                    $(element).hide();
                }
                else {
                    $(element).show();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 7):

The best way to do this is to use **response interceptors** along with custom **directive**. And the process can further be improved using **pub/sub** mechanism using *$rootScope.$broadcast* & *$rootScope.$on* methods.

As the whole process is documented in a well written [blog article](http://codingsmackdown.tv/blog/2013/04/20/using-response-interceptors-to-show-and-hide-a-loading-widget-redux/), I'm not going to repeat that here again. Please refer to that article to come up with your needed implementation.

Answer (score 4):

In reference of this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17144634/4146239

For me is the best solution but there's a way to avoid use jQuery.

```js
.directive('loading', function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:true,
        template: '<div class="loading"><img src="http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/videogallery/ajax-loader.gif" width="20" height="20" />LOADING...</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
              scope.$watch('loading', function (val) {
                  if (val)
                      scope.loadingStatus = 'true';
                  else
                      scope.loadingStatus = 'false';
              });
        }
      }
  })

  .controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.cars = [];
      
      $scope.clickMe = function() {
        scope.loadingStatus = 'true'
        $http.get('test.json')
          .success(function(data) {
            $scope.cars = data[0].cars;
            $scope.loadingStatus = 'false';
        });
      }
      
  });
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" ng-init="loadingStatus='true'">
        <loading ng-show="loadingStatus" ></loading>
  
        <div ng-repeat="car in cars">
          <li>{{car.name}}</li>
        </div>
        <button ng-click="clickMe()" class="btn btn-primary">CLICK ME</button>
  
</body>
```

You need to replace $(element).show(); and (element).show(); with $scope.loadingStatus = 'true'; and $scope.loadingStatus = 'false';

Than, you need to use this variable to set the ng-show attribute of the element.

Answer (score 4):

**Typescript and Angular Implementation**

**directive**

```
((): void=> {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("app").directive("busyindicator", busyIndicator);
    function busyIndicator($http:ng.IHttpService): ng.IDirective {
        var directive = <ng.IDirective>{
            restrict: "A",
            link(scope: Scope.IBusyIndicatorScope) {
                scope.anyRequestInProgress = () => ($http.pendingRequests.length > 0);
                scope.$watch(scope.anyRequestInProgress, x => {            
                    if (x) {
                        scope.canShow = true;
                    } else {
                        scope.canShow = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        return directive;
    }
})();
```

**Scope**

```
   module App.Scope {
        export interface IBusyIndicatorScope extends angular.IScope {
            anyRequestInProgress: any;
            canShow: boolean;
        }
    }
```

**Template**

```
<div id="activityspinner" ng-show="canShow" class="show" data-busyindicator>
</div>

CSS
#activityspinner
{
    display : none;
}
#activityspinner.show {
    display : block;
    position : fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    background-image : url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhNgA3APMAAPz8/GZmZqysrHV1dW1tbeXl5ZeXl+fn59nZ2ZCQkLa2tgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH/C05FVFNDQVBFMi4wAwEAAAAh/hpDcmVhdGVkIHdpdGggYWpheGxvYWQuaW5mbwAh+QQJCgAAACwAAAAANgA3AAAEzBDISau9OOvNu/9gKI5kaZ4lkhBEgqCnws6EApMITb93uOqsRC8EpA1Bxdnx8wMKl51ckXcsGFiGAkamsy0LA9pAe1EFqRbBYCAYXXUGk4DWJhZN4dlAlMSLRW80cSVzM3UgB3ksAwcnamwkB28GjVCWl5iZmpucnZ4cj4eWoRqFLKJHpgSoFIoEe5ausBeyl7UYqqw9uaVrukOkn8LDxMXGx8ibwY6+JLxydCO3JdMg1dJ/Is+E0SPLcs3Jnt/F28XXw+jC5uXh4u89EQAh+QQJCgAAACwAAAAANgA3AAAEzhDISau9OOvNu/9gKI5kaZ5oqhYGQRiFWhaD6w6xLLa2a+iiXg8YEtqIIF7vh/QcarbB4YJIuBKIpuTAM0wtCqNiJBgMBCaE0ZUFCXpoknWdCEFvpfURdCcM8noEIW82cSNzRnWDZoYjamttWhphQmOSHFVXkZecnZ6foKFujJdlZxqELo1AqQSrFH1/TbEZtLM9shetrzK7qKSSpryixMXGx8jJyifCKc1kcMzRIrYl1Xy4J9cfvibdIs/MwMue4cffxtvE6qLoxubk8ScRACH5BAkKAAAALAAAAAA2ADcAAATOEMhJq7046827/2AojmRpnmiqrqwwDAJbCkRNxLI42MSQ6zzfD0Sz4YYfFwyZKxhqhgJJeSQVdraBNFSsVUVPHsEAzJrEtnJNSELXRN2bKcwjw19f0QG7PjA7B2EGfn+FhoeIiYoSCAk1CQiLFQpoChlUQwhuBJEWcXkpjm4JF3w9P5tvFqZsLKkEF58/omiksXiZm52SlGKWkhONj7vAxcbHyMkTmCjMcDygRNAjrCfVaqcm11zTJrIjzt64yojhxd/G28XqwOjG5uTxJhEAIfkECQoAAAAsAAAAADYANwAABM0QyEmrvTjrzbv/YCiOZGmeaKqurDAMAlsKRE3EsjjYxJDrPN8PRLPhhh8XDMk0KY/OF5TIm4qKNWtnZxOWuDUvCNw7kcXJ6gl7Iz1T76Z8Tq/b7/i8qmCoGQoacT8FZ4AXbFopfTwEBhhnQ4w2j0GRkgQYiEOLPI6ZUkgHZwd6EweLBqSlq6ytricICTUJCKwKkgojgiMIlwS1VEYlspcJIZAkvjXHlcnKIZokxJLG0KAlvZfAebeMuUi7FbGz2z/Rq8jozavn7Nev8CsRACH5BAkKAAAALAAAAAA2ADcAAATLEMhJq7046827/2AojmRpnmiqrqwwDAJbCkRNxLI42MSQ6zzfD0Sz4YYfFwzJNCmPzheUyJuKijVrZ2cTlrg1LwjcO5HFyeoJeyM9U++mfE6v2+/4PD6O5F/YWiqAGWdIhRiHP4kWg0ONGH4/kXqUlZaXmJlMBQY1BgVuUicFZ6AhjyOdPAQGQF0mqzauYbCxBFdqJao8rVeiGQgJNQkIFwdnB0MKsQrGqgbJPwi2BMV5wrYJetQ129x62LHaedO21nnLq82VwcPnIhEAIfkECQoAAAAsAAAAADYANwAABMwQyEmrvTjrzbv/YCiOZGmeaKqurDAMAlsKRE3EsjjYxJDrPN8PRLPhhh8XDMk0KY/OF5TIm4qKNWtnZxOWuDUvCNw7kcXJ6gl7Iz1T76Z8Tq/b7/g8Po7kX9haKoAZZ0iFGIc/iRaDQ40Yfj+RepSVlpeYAAgJNQkIlgo8NQqUCKI2nzNSIpynBAkzaiCuNl9BIbQ1tl0hraewbrIfpq6pbqsioaKkFwUGNQYFSJudxhUFZ9KUz6IGlbTfrpXcPN6UB2cHlgfcBuqZKBEAIfkECQoAAAAsAAAAADYANwAABMwQyEmrvTjrzbv/YCiOZGmeaKqurDAMAlsKRE3EsjjYxJDrPN8PRLPhhh8XDMk0KY/OF5TIm4qKNWtnZxOWuDUvCNw7kcXJ6gl7Iz1T76Z8Tq/b7yJEopZA4CsKPDUKfxIIgjZ+P3EWe4gECYtqFo82P2cXlTWXQReOiJE5bFqHj4qiUhmBgoSFho59rrKztLVMBQY1BgWzBWe8UUsiuYIGTpMglSaYIcpfnSHEPMYzyB8HZwdrqSMHxAbath2MsqO0zLLorua05OLvJxEAIfkECQoAAAAsAAAAADYANwAABMwQyEmrvTjrzbv/YCiOZGmeaKqurDAMAlsKRE3EsjjYxJDrPN8PRLPhfohELYHQuGBDgIJXU0Q5CKqtOXsdP0otITHjfTtiW2lnE37StXUwFNaSScXaGZvm4r0jU1RWV1hhTIWJiouMjVcFBjUGBY4WBWw1A5RDT3sTkVQGnGYYaUOYPaVip3MXoDyiP3k3GAeoAwdRnRoHoAa5lcHCw8TFxscduyjKIrOeRKRAbSe3I9Um1yHOJ9sjzCbfyInhwt3E2cPo5dHF5OLvJREAOwAAAAAAAAAAAA==') 
    -ms-opacity : 0.4;
    opacity : 0.4;
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
    background-position : center;
    left : 0;
    bottom : 0;
    right : 0;
    top : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Restangular (which is awesome) you can create an animation during api calls. Here is my solution. Add a response interceptor and a request interceptor that sends out a rootscope broadcast. Then create a directive to listen for that response and request.:

```
         angular.module('mean.system')
  .factory('myRestangular',['Restangular','$rootScope', function(Restangular,$rootScope) {
    return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
      RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:3000/api');
      RestangularConfigurer.addResponseInterceptor(function(data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
        var extractedData;
        // .. to look for getList operations
        if (operation === 'getList') {
          // .. and handle the data and meta data
          extractedData = data.data;
          extractedData.meta = data.meta;
        } else {
          extractedData = data.data;
        }
        $rootScope.$broadcast('apiResponse');
        return extractedData;
      });
      RestangularConfigurer.setRequestInterceptor(function (elem, operation) {
        if (operation === 'remove') {
          return null;
        }
        return (elem && angular.isObject(elem.data)) ? elem : {data: elem};
      });
      RestangularConfigurer.setRestangularFields({
        id: '_id'
      });
      RestangularConfigurer.addRequestInterceptor(function(element, operation, what, url) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('apiRequest');
        return element;
      });
    });
  }]);
```

Here is the directive:

```
        angular.module('mean.system')
  .directive('smartLoadingIndicator', function($rootScope) {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      template: '<div ng-show="isAPICalling"><p><i class="fa fa-gear fa-4x fa-spin"></i>&nbsp;Loading</p></div>',
      replace: true,
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.isAPICalling = false;

        $rootScope.$on('apiRequest', function() {
          scope.isAPICalling = true;
        });
        $rootScope.$on('apiResponse', function() {
          scope.isAPICalling = false;
        });
      }
    };
  })
;
```

Comment: Any API response will kill animation. You should store additional information about request - response, and react only for that respond that was initialized by request.

Answer (score 3):

Include this in your "app.config":

```
 $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```

And add this code:

```
app.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function ($q, $window,$rootScope) {
    $rootScope.ActiveAjaxConectionsWithouthNotifications = 0;
    var checker = function(parameters,status){
            //YOU CAN USE parameters.url TO IGNORE SOME URL
            if(status == "request"){
                $rootScope.ActiveAjaxConectionsWithouthNotifications+=1;
                $('#loading_view').show();
            }
            if(status == "response"){
                $rootScope.ActiveAjaxConectionsWithouthNotifications-=1;

            }
            if($rootScope.ActiveAjaxConectionsWithouthNotifications<=0){
                $rootScope.ActiveAjaxConectionsWithouthNotifications=0;
                $('#loading_view').hide();

            }


    };
return {
    'request': function(config) {
        checker(config,"request");
        return config;
    },
   'requestError': function(rejection) {
       checker(rejection.config,"request");
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    },
    'response': function(response) {
         checker(response.config,"response");
      return response;
    },
   'responseError': function(rejection) {
        checker(rejection.config,"response");
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, there is a nice demo that shows how can you use `Angularjs` animation in your project.

The link is [here](http://yearofmoo-articles.github.io/angularjs-animation-article/app/#/ng-repeat)
**(See the top left corner)**.

It's an open source. Here is the link to [download](https://github.com/yearofmoo-articles/AngularJS-Animation-Article)

And here is the link for [tutorial](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/04/animation-in-angularjs.html);

My point is, go ahead and download the source files and then see how they have implemented the spinner. They might have used a little better aproach. So, checkout this project.

Answer (score 2):

Use [angular-busy](https://github.com/cgross/angular-busy):

Add cgBusy as to your app / module:

```
angular.module('your_app', ['cgBusy']);
```

Add your promise to `scope`:

```
function MyCtrl($http, User) {
  //using $http
  this.isBusy = $http.get('...');
  //if you have a User class based on $resource
  this.isBusy = User.$save();
}
```

In your html template:

```
<div cg-busy="$ctrl.isBusy"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here simple interceptor example, I set mouse on wait when ajax starts and set it to auto when ajax ends.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($document) {
return {
 'request': function(config) {
     // here ajax start
     // here we can for example add some class or show somethin
     $document.find("body").css("cursor","wait");

     return config;
  },

  'response': function(response) {
     // here ajax ends
     //here we should remove classes added on request start

     $document.find("body").css("cursor","auto");

     return response;
  }
};
});
```

Code has to be added in application config `app.config`. I showed how to change mouse on loading state but in there it is possible to show/hide any loader content, or add, remove some css classes which are showing the loader.

Interceptor will run on every ajax call, so no need to create special boolean variables ( $scope.loading=true/false etc. ) on every http call.

Interceptor is using builded in angular **jqLite** https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element so no Jquery needed.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Directive with the show and size attributes ( you can add more also )

```
    app.directive('loader',function(){
    return {
    restrict:'EA',
    scope:{
        show : '@',
      size : '@'
    },
    template : '<div class="loader-container"><div class="loader" ng-if="show" ng-class="size"></div></div>'
  }
})
```

and in html use as

```
 <loader show="{{loader1}}" size="sm"></loader>
```

In the **show** variable pass *true* when any promise is running and make that *false* when request is completed.
Active demo - [Angular Loader directive example demo in JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/btvypscw/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I built on @DavidLin's answer a little to simplify it - **removing any dependency on jQuery** in the directive. I can confirm this works as I use it in a production application

```
function AjaxLoadingOverlay($http) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attributes) {

            $scope.loadingOverlay = false;

            $scope.isLoading = function () {
                return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
            };

            $scope.$watch($scope.isLoading, function (isLoading) {
                $scope.loadingOverlay = isLoading;
            });
        }
    };
}
```

I use a `ng-show` instead of a jQuery call to hide/show the `<div>`.

Here's the `<div>` which I placed just below the opening `<body>` tag:

```
<div ajax-loading-overlay class="loading-overlay" ng-show="loadingOverlay">
    <img src="Resources/Images/LoadingAnimation.gif" />
</div>
```

And here's the CSS that provides the overlay to block UI while a $http call is being made:

```
.loading-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    overflow: show;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.loading-overlay:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

/* :not(:required) hides these rules from IE9 and below */
.loading-overlay:not(:required) {
    font: 0/0 a;
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
}
```

CSS credit goes to @Steve Seeger's - his post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35470281/335545

Answer (score 0):

***You could add a condition and then change it via the rootscope. Before your ajax request, you simply call $rootScope.$emit('stopLoader');***

```
angular.module('directive.loading', [])
        .directive('loading',   ['$http', '$rootScope',function ($http, $rootScope)
        {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function (scope, elm, attrs)
                {
                    scope.isNoLoadingForced = false;
                    scope.isLoading = function () {
                        return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0 && scope.isNoLoadingForced;
                    };

                    $rootScope.$on('stopLoader', function(){
                        scope.isNoLoadingForced = true;
                    })

                    scope.$watch(scope.isLoading, function (v)
                    {
                        if(v){
                            elm.show();
                        }else{
                            elm.hide();
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

        }]);
```

**This is definatly not the best solution but it would still works.**