# Change ng-view after get data in Angular.JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm going to get some data from server using $http and JSON response. `$http.get()` are called after route change. But template are changed before data is downloaded. My goal is:

- User press a hyperlink in menu, that changes a route,
- Shows Loading Spinner (DOM Element is in another controller which is on page everytime)
- Initializing `$scope.init()` (via `ng-init="init()"`) in controller which is in my new template, this also initializing get data from server
- Data are downloaded, now I can hide spinner and change visible template

How can I do this? My App looks for example:

Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.init = function() {
       $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://ip.jsontest.com/'}).success(function(data) {
           console.log(data);
               $scope.ip = data.ip;
           });
    }
});

myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/link', {
        controller: 'MyCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'embeded.tpl.html'
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="embeded.tpl.html">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-init="init()">
    Your IP Address is: {{ip}}
    </div>
</script>

<div>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#/link">change route</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you looked at this thread?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144180/angularjs-loading-screen-on-ajax-request

Comment: Yes, but that's not what I need.

Comment: Why don't you simply send the http request when the controller is constructed, and have a view like `<div ng-show="ip">...</div>` (i.e. it doesn't show anything until the data is received)?

Comment: I would rather change the page structure. I don't think ng-view is the best solution for you. Maybe you could work with with ngInclude to change just what you need to update in your page. Have the url change a significant role in your application logic? Do you use some url parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to resolve data before routing happens, thus, move your $http to config section.

This is good tutorial for that, http://www.thinkster.io/pick/6cmY50Dsyf/angularjs-resolve-conventions

This is config part.

```
 $routeProvider.when('/link', {
    controller: 'MyCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'embeded.tpl.html',
    resolve: {
      data: function ($q, $http) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://ip.jsontest.com/'}).then(function(data) {
          deferred.resolve(data);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    }
 }
```

and this is controller part

```
//`data` is injected from routeProvider after resolved
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http, data) { 
  $scope.ip = data.ip
});
```

I think promise in AngularJS is very important concept for any async. processing.
You need to use this technique every time you have callback.

Comment: That's it! But I've a just one question. Is it possible to use ngResource in resolve object?

Comment: The question is 'Does ngResource returns promise?'. if so `return MyResource.get({id: $route.current.params.id});`, if not `return MyResource.get({id: $route.current.params.id}).promise;`.

Comment: My question is, does ngResource can be used in resolve convention :) Just instead `$http.get()` I want use `MyRes.get()`

Comment: as it said here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/16759067/454252, `return MyRes.get().$promise;`

Comment: Yes, but I don't need define my resource somewhere (just like in controller)? It looks: `Controllers.controller('dashboardCtrl', ['$scope', 'DashboardRes', function($scope, Res) {...}]);`. My Resource looks that: `app.factory('DashboardRes', ['$resource', function($resource) {...});`, without create new variable.

Answer (score 1):

I will not do it all for you, however I will point you in the right direction.

First you need the `ngRoute` module.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

And the JS file:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Now you routes will be working and you do not need to call a special `init` function in your controller since they get instanciated on every route change when used with `ng-view`.

For the spinner, you could add some interceptors to all ajax requests using the `$httpProvider`. Inside the interceptors you could `emit` some events on the `$rootScope` and listen to then in a specialed custom attribute directive e.g. `spinner` where the magic would occur ;)