# Http progress function?

Tags: angularjs, http, progress

```
$http({
  url: Config.ApiURL + "/site/go",
  method: "POST",
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  data: $.param(testimony)
}).progress(function (data, status, headers, config) { //Not sure about this line
  console.log('progressing');
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('success');
});
```

I want to display something before it successes or error, so im not sure about `.progress` part, i just inserted it there as an example and for you to imagine my problem.. is it possible? is there a built-in function for that?

BTW, im new to angular. TIA :)

Comment: You need a directive. There is already a post an SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144180/angularjs-loading-screen-on-ajax-request

Answer (score 0):

According to some post I found on github (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1934 , see the post from 26th april 2014), you should be able to do it like that :

```
 $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl',progress:trackProgress}).then(function(result){
       // handle result
```

});

Where `tarckProgress` would be a callback to call to handle the progress state.

Comment: I know that also the third parameter of the `then` function is the the notify callback. This can be hooked into the XHR progress update

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the progress spinner / bar, and in addition to that if you want to show something else, you can use [angular-loading-bar](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/)