# Waiting Angularjs during application load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have multiple modules in my application. And I have so many directives, ajax get operations.

I want to show a loading notification to user during my application first load. Because some of application settings are coming from server via ajax.

Is there any angular options to wait applciation load.

Answer (score 0):

Bam! Two blogs with great ideas on how to get this going.

I have used this one for my own projects really simple, just waiting to see if the route is ready to load, its using ui-router. https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/angularjs-two-ways-loading-animations/

Another stack-overflow question similar to yours, the commenter goes on to explain a simple directive for the load screen while your application loads up.
[Angularjs loading screen on ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144180/angularjs-loading-screen-on-ajax-request)

If you need more info look up 'angular application load screen' on google and you will get some good hits.Hope this helps!