# How to add loader in angular app

Tags: angularjs, loader

I want to show a loader before any api call, after getiing response hide the loader.It should be like generic, i have tried inspector that is not working for me.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144180/angularjs-loading-screen-on-ajax-request

Answer (score 0):

You could use angular-loading-bar, it uses interceptors to show a loading bar as long as there is pending requests.

http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/

Answer (score 0):

Create loader using directive. Add a parent to the loader element.

loader.directive.js

```
app.directive('loaderDir', function(){
  return{
     restrict: 'AE',
     scope:{},
     template: 'loader template here.......',
  }
})
```

index.html

```
   <body>
      <div loader-dir class="loader-holder" id="loader-holder"></div>    //better make this as last child
   </body>
```

styles.css

```
.loader-holder{
   display: none;
}
.loader-show{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

ajaxCall.service.js

```
function makeRequest(){
  //when you are going to make request, show loader that means addClass `loader-show`
  angular.element(document.getElementById('loader-holder')).addClass('loader-show');
  $http.get(url).then(function success(response){
   // on successful response, hide loader that means removeClass `loader-show`
     angular.element(document.getElementById('loader-holder')).removeClass('loader-show');
  })
}
```