# preload images after $http request with angular service promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, preload

i need to preload images after an $http service.

Now in my application i'm using promise/resolve method to preload data with service.
here my service:

```
angular.module('davelab.services', [])

.factory('srvProjects', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var API = '/backend/api/';

    var sdo = {

        getProjects: function() {

            var promise = $http({ method: 'GET', url:  API + 'get_posts/' }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                return data;
            });

            return promise;

        }

    };

    return sdo;


}]);
});
```

and  here the route part:

```
 $routeProvider.when('/projects', {
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/list-projects.html',
        controller: 'ProjectsCtrl',
        resolve: {
                projects: function(srvProjects) {
                return srvProjects.getProjects();
            }
        }
    });
```

it works well with data but for the images retrieved from api request it doesn't work.

How can I preload images in cache before show the view with this method?

i have to iterate through data into success callback or somewhere else?

thanks.

Comment: What do you mean images? Data containing links to images? Or you are actually using `$http` to try to return a binary image?

Comment: i mean url(s) of images

Answer (score 1):

Take the URL's you're receiving from your original request, but instead of resolving the promise right away, create a new promise for each image. Preload the image using any [method](http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/) you prefer (but it needs a callback to resolve its promise) and resolve each promise after the image is loaded. You should end up with an array of image promises. and then return `$q.all(imagePromises)`  from your resolve. Check out the [docs for $q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q).

`$q.all` will return a promise that is only resolved when all promises passed into it are resolved.

I haven't tested it, but I think you might be able to just use `$http` on each image URL and it will cache it for you and give you a nice promise to pass into `$q.all`. So basically you'll have an array of `$http` calls.

Comment: can i add this to $http success callback?  `var img = [];
     angular.forEach(data.posts, function(value, key){
       
       img[key] = new Image();
       img[key].src = value.custom_fields.projectCover;
     });`

Comment: Just try `img = []; angular.ForEach(data.posts, function(value){ img.push($http(value.custom_fields.projectCover)); });` followed by `$q.all(img)`

Comment: i got this error with your advise: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined`

Comment: i added 'method' and 'url' params to $http service for each image but it still doesn't work. I mean is not anymore a progressive loading but show once a time every single image when is loaded. (in order of sizes, obviously),

Comment: Hard to say what it is without seeing your exact code. Sounds like the path isn't getting passed to $http properly.

Comment: this is the code: `var promise = $http({ method: 'GET', url:  API + 'get_posts/' }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

 var img = []; 
 angular.forEach(data.posts, function(value){ 
  img.push($http({ method: 'GET', url:  value.custom_fields.projectCover })); 
  
 }); 

 $q.all(img);

 return data;
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this in your controller

```
$scope.preloader = true
```

then you can use angular promise of

```
.then(function(result){
  //your code goes here

  $scope.preloader = false;
}
```

Also you have $scope.preloader= false in you error block

If you have multiple Ajax calls at a same time parallely then use

```
$scope.preloader = 0;
```

on stating the request use

```
$scope.preloader++;
```

and when done use

```
$scope.preloader--;
```

You can have more clear answer here
[Showing Spinner GIF during $http request in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033195/showing-spinner-gif-during-http-request-in-angular#answer-15033322)