# Loading animation for every AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I built an AngularJS frontend which communicates with a REST API backend.
Whenever I access remote data via Angular's `$http` object I want to display a loading animation (gif or CSS3).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15033322) works really well, but needs manual setup for each request. I am looking for a more generic solution that sets a variable `loading` to `true` whenever a `$http` request is made in my factories and not only when I set it to `true` or `false` manually.