# Load Angular Spinner on http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spinner, jquery-spinner

I'm trying to use Angular Spin Kit in my project to load the spinner on every http GET,PUT,POST and DELETE method.
Here's the fiddle for Angular Spin Kit.

[Angular Spin kit](http://jsfiddle.net/mailmrmanoj/wcmh6bwd/)

```
<circle-spinner></circle-spinner>
```

How can I connect this spinner with my controller code so that when a http call gets invoked I can load this spinner in my view.Thanks

Comment: Could you please add a link to a JS fiddle or Plnkr with your code or something that you've tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried yet.I wanted to know the way how this can be linked with the GET requests in the controller

Comment: You can use `$http` service interceptors, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033195/showing-spinner-gif-during-http-request-in-angular

Comment: checkout my [factory](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-httpshooter), i think it will help you out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use a `$scope` variable to detect a progressing of a ajax request. based on that variable you can show or hide the spinner

```
 $scope.sendAjax = function() {
    $scope.prograssing = true;                // show spinner
    $http.get('data.json').then(function() {
      //sucess
      $scope.prograssing = false;          // hide spinner when success ajax
    } , function() {
      //error
      $scope.prograssing = false;        // hide spinner when unsuccessful ajax
    });
 }
```

here is the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/q9mCulTJSODlhOAK70Ls?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to follow these instructions on how to install [angular-spinkit](https://github.com/Urigo/angular-spinkit/blob/master/README.md) in your project.

Second of all, **[please see this Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fa3CHLMSYBJpHqLKbn7c?p=preview)** to see how I managed to use angular spinkit for GET calls.

These are the main steps:

1. Insert your `<circle-spinner></circle-spinner>` directive into the code but make it invisible using `ng-show` like this:

   `<circle-spinner ng-show="showSpinner"></circle-spinner>`

   `showSpinner` is a $scope variable that we iniate as `false` as we don't want the spinning circle to show until we make the `$http` call.
2. Make your GET call using the angular `$http` service. Use a function to do so. When you call the function, the first thing is to set the `$scope.showSpinner` variable to `true` so your spinner is visible. Then you make the `$http` call.
3. Next step is to handle the GET response. When the call is finished (you have the success or the error options), you have to tell the `$scope.showSpinner` variable to become false which means the `ng-show` from the `<circle-spinner>` directive will become false so the circle is not displayed anymore.

Long story short, you show an invisible spinning circle, you make an `$http` call that makes it visible; when the response is back, the spinning circle is not visible anymore.