# Show loader before getting response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

Need to show loader image before getting response
I used the code below:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in cus_names">
                <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
                <td>{{x.City}}</td>
                <td>{{x.Country}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php").success(function (response) {
        $scope.cus_names = response.records;
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no default loading icons in angular you only to implement

Comment: Can u please give another option for that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing Spinner GIF during $http request in angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033195/showing-spinner-gif-during-http-request-in-angular)

Comment: @DawidFerenczy All those answers are obsolete and overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `ready` flag and use that to show or not show your loading image.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
            <div ng-if="!ready">
               <!-- Put loading image here -->
            </div>
            <div ng-if="ready">
               <tr ng-repeat="x in cus_names">
                   <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
                   <td>{{x.City}}</td>
                   <td>{{x.Country}}</td>
               </tr>
            </div>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp").controller('customersCtrl', 
    function customersCtrl ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.ready = false;
        $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php"
            ) .then (function (response) {
                $scope.cus_names = response.data.records;
                $scope.ready = true; 
            }) .catch (function (error) {
                throw error;
            });
    }
);
```

Note that the `.success` method is now deprecated and we should be using `.then` from now on. For more information on that see the [AngularJS $http API Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).