# How to show loading message while sending angularj http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loading

I want to show a loading message while sending http request and hide loading   on request complete, and i want to use this for all the http request. Is there any global function in angular to do this..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing Spinner GIF during $http request in angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033195/showing-spinner-gif-during-http-request-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

A JavaScript HTTP request will not block and you will provide a callback which is called when the request is complete. This means that you could do this (pseudocode, since you didn't provide example code):

```
function callback(httpResponse) {
  hideLoadingMessage();
  dostuffWithResponse(httpResponse);
}
// callback is callled when HTTP request is complete
doHttpRequest(params, callback);
// the code after continues to execute despite the HTTP request not being ready
showLoadingMessage();
```

So the code execution continues after the HTTP request is sent. The callback will be called when the HTTP request is complete. In practice you need to also handle errors.

Comment: This answer isn't really appropriate for an angularjs application where  you would use a service returning a promise rather than a callback and instead of functions to show or hide a message you simply manipulate the data model appropriately. See the 'possible duplicate' suggestion for more appropriate answers. Specifically http://stackoverflow.com/a/15033322/107660

Answer (score 0):

Quick Google search returned a fair amount of results for Angular:

Loading spinner you can implement onClick.

http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-loading-spinner

Previously asked question with similar circumstances:

[Showing Spinner GIF during $http request in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033195/showing-spinner-gif-during-http-request-in-angular)

And finally, codepen.io examples (might be broken now though)

http://codetunnel.io/how-to-do-loading-spinners-the-angular-way/

I would highly recommend trying before asking in future. We need code examples of what you've tried or where you are at right now. This isn't a simple piece of code unless you're using a plugin (which you could have found yourself).

I'd recommend in future, try providing some context and examples.