# AngularJS show loading in parent view until http data in parent and childs views are loaded

Tags: angularjs

I have a html view with its controller and I have some  ng-includes (HTML + controller) in this parent view.

In every controllers (parent and childs) I load HTTP data for populate some controls

So far I showed a preloading image in the parent view but this preloading stop when parent data in parent controller is loaded.

Today I need the preloader in the parent still stay untill all data in every child controller are loaded (because now we have a lot of data in every child and want wait for all data and then hide the preloading).

What is the best way of listening from my parent controller all the data loaded in every child controllers in order to hide the preloader in the parent view when all data in all childs are loaded.

Can it be done with ng-init on every ng-included view and using a callback?

Every http load is in every controller because I want to keep modularity because every ng-include (every child) can be like a control I can remove.
For example, can be some option list.

What should I use in the parent controller for and be sue all the HTTP data in every child is loaded. The optimal way of doing this because the NG-IF of the preloading only must be set to false when all controller child have its data.
How listenig every child form a parent controller

Please Is very important for me because every way I try don´t work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show us some code, or set up a jsFiddle with a working example.  Otherwise, we simply don't have enough info to help.

Comment: sounds like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033195/showing-spinner-gif-during-http-request-in-angular