# how to make a common spin for each controllers?

Tags: angularjs

I have angular js project having several controllers, each controllers i am using so many api calls which take much time, so i would like to put loading spin in each page when api call is made.

i want to keep a rootscope variable like

```
 $rootScope.showLoading=false;
```

when ever i make this variable from any controller like

```
  $rootScope.showLoadin=true;
```

then the spin should come, when i make it false, spin should go off.

how accomplish it?

Comment: This can help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033195/showing-spinner-gif-during-http-request-in-angular

Comment: Someone already did what you want : http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the loader for every http request your app makes, keeping track of the number of active and resolved requests. So for every request `xhrCreations` is added by `1`, and for every resolved `xhrResolutions` is added by `1`.

So if the number of active requests are more than resolved, the service will be updated with a value of `true`. And then when no requests are active the service will be updated with `false`. Thus hiding your loader from the controller since the scope variable is set to `false`.

```
core.factory('httpInterceptor', ['$q', 'globalStates', function ($q, globalStates) {

    var xhrCreations = 0,
            xhrResolutions = 0;

    function isLoading() {
        return xhrResolutions < xhrCreations;
    }

    return {
        request: function (req) {

            xhrCreations++;

            globalStates.set('isRequestActive', isLoading());

            return req;
        },
        requestError: function (err) {

            xhrResolutions++;

            globalStates.set('isRequestActive', isLoading());

            return $q.reject(err);
        },
        response: function (res) {

            xhrResolutions++;

            globalStates.set('isRequestActive', isLoading());

            return res;
        },
        responseError: function (err) {

            xhrResolutions++;

            globalStates.set('isRequestActive', isLoading());

            return $q.reject(err);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Service:

```
core.service('globalStates', [function() {

  var gs = this;

  var states = {};

  gs.set = function(k, v) {
    states[k] = v;
  };

  gs.get = function(k) {
    return k ? states[k] : states;
  };
}]);
```

Then you can access the value in the service via a watcher from your core controller:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
  return globalStates.get();
}, function(states) {
  $rootScope.showLoading = states.isLoading;
});
```

Comment: could you explain it a little bit?

Comment: @Vispriya There you go.

Comment: @Vispriya Did this help you?