# AngularJS : Showing a spinner while during $http request

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-http

I put in place some routes with the `$routeProvider`.
The place is that some templates need some time to load because of the `$http` requests.

What I wanted to do is to display a spinner or a wait message in the `<div ng-view></div>` while the `$http` is doing his job. When it finishes, it hides that spinner or wait text.

Is it possible with AngularJS ?

Regards.

Comment: Maybe you should look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31954859/988957

Comment: Yes! And this has been answered here. [Spinner in Angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033195/showing-spinner-gif-during-http-request-in-angular)