# How to create Loading directive with attribute for an Ajax Request

Tags: angularjs

I have multiple DIV & Separate AJAX Request for all DIV. I want to use loader using directive. Like `<myloading ng-show="isLoad"></myloading>`

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing Spinner GIF during $http request in angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033195/showing-spinner-gif-during-http-request-in-angular)

Comment: No need to re-invent a bicycle. The functionality is implemented already. See https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar